# How to check whether user accepted the installation of the apk via intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, installation, apk

In my application I implemented the self-update, so as soon as the application is opened, it compares its version with version of the apk on the server. If there is an update it downloads the apk from the ftp server and its version. I store version of the application in Shared Preferences. When the apk is downloaded I use following code to install the downloaded apk:

```
PackageInfo pInfo = null;
        try {
            pInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
            String version = pInfo.versionName;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + path);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = prefs.edit();
        ed.putString("version", String.valueOf(ver));
        ed.apply();

        context.startActivity(intent);
```

Simultaneously I update the value in SharedPreferences. However user can decline the installation, then the update isn`t installed but values in SharedPreferences are updated. Is there any way to block usage of the app if user declines the installation? Or how can I check whether he accepted the installation.

Comment: You can not. But you can add receiver to listen package-install and then add validations to check for required application is installed or not. This way you can track, user has installed application or not.

Comment: @PankajKumar the problem is, that it is self-updating, so no new package is not created, everything happens in already existing package

Comment: Then you can register a receiver targeted to `android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED` action to check if user has updated your application or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Simultaneously I update the value in SharedPreferences. However user
>   can decline the installation, then the update isn`t installed but
>   values in SharedPreferences are updated

Do not update the version while asking for installing new apk!
**Rather update the version code after the launch of application** then you can check with the latest one to allow or reject user and relaunch install.

```
int versionCode = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
String versionName = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
```